# Can 4 fields be put together to use as a key to join two tables?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to create a solution which allows pilots to swap a 1, 2, 3 or 4 day trip for another pilot's 1, 2, 3 or 4 day trip. I have 3 tables, Pilot, Have and Want. A pilot creates a Have which, for example, is a 2 day on 10/20 (October 20th). This pilot wants a 3 day starting on the 22. Another pilot has the 3 day and he wants something like the other pilot's 2 day. The tables looks like this;

```
id_pilot, name,   phone,      employee_num, aircraft, base, seat
1         Steve   363-0040    123454        320       DCA   FO
2         Ted     992-5380    123455        320       DCA   FO

id_have,  id_pilot,  daytrip,  start_month, start_day
1         1          02        10           20
2         2          03        10           22

id_want,  id_have,   daytrip,  start_month, start_day
1         1          03        10           22
```

To see what Wants are out there for a particular Have I need to join the Want and Have table on something that looks like DCA|320|FO|10|20|2. I only want to see the Wants for a particular Have that are for the aircraft, base and seat. I can do this by creating a new join field but having such a simplistic understanding of MySQL I imagine there is a way to do this on the fly. I used joins to grab information via the primary keys but this seems like it's one step removed from that. What would such a query look like?

Comment: I think it would be a lot easier to create a `trips` table and another table that handles scheduling/assignment of/to trips in it. You should always avoid creating multiple tables which are almost the same in structure. Your design is prone to so many challenges.

Comment: `join` clauses can be as arbitrarily complex as you want. they DON'T have to be a simple single-field `join foo on foo.x = bar.y`. The only requirement is that they evaluate to a simple boolean true/false. that means you can as incredibly nastily ugly complicated logic as you want. `join ... on a=b and (c=d or e=f) and world_peace_achieved()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give an example of what Marc B is saying, the join clause can compare the *daytrip*, *start_month* and *start_date* columns between the *have* and *want* tables, e.g.

```
select have.id_pilot, want.id_pilot, want.daytrip, want.start_month, want.start_day
from have
inner join want
on have.daytrip = want.daytrip
and have.start_month = want.start_month
and have.start_day = want.start_day
```

The 'on' clause is executed on each row comparison between the two tables and the only absolute is that it must return true or false.  So any column from either table can be used in the evaluation in any combination.